# Horizontal form on mobile view

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to draw an horizontal form that should be horizontal even on mobile view.
Currently I have this simple form:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="username">{{_USERNAME}}:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="username" value="{{username}}">
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

It works correctly as expected, so it is horizontal on large screens and classic on small screens.

Current:
[image: one]

Expected:
[image: two]

How can I force this form to be horizontal even on small screens? Do I have to write CSS by myself or there is some standard way using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've found the solution.
Use **`col-xs-*`** instead of **`col-ms-*`**

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="username">{{_USERNAME}}:</label>
     <div class="col-xs-10">
       <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="username" value="{{username}}">
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since non of the above met my needs. I drawed a table and inserted the label inside a td and the input in the next td. All within the same row. Finally adjusted the margins as needed.

Note: This worked for an exclusive mobile UX.